# Nginx and Tomcat - subdomain pointing to subdirectory

Tags: tomcat, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have the following configuration for my application *example.com*:

1. Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect traffic from port 80 to:
2. Tomcat 7 where I deploy my JSF app, port 8080
3. My xhtml files are mostly in the ROOT folder: /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
4. But I have some files in a separate folder "forum": /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/forum

This is my default nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     example.com.br;
  root            /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT;
  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

So, to access the forum page I have to go to *example.com/forum/forum.xhtml* (forum.xhtml is the index)

Now, I'm trying to set a **subdomain**, *forum.example.com*, in nginx, that will point to the forum folder, **keeping the URL**. That is, I don't want ever to see the sufix "/forum/" in the URL. I want that the forum folder behaves as the **root**. So if the user tries *forum.example.com/anotherPageFromROOT.xhtml* he will not be able to.

This is what I have so far:

```
server {
 listen          80;
 server_name     forum.example.com;

 location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
       rewrite ^/$ /forum/forum.xhtml break;    
 }
}
```

Problems:

1. If I click in a link (POST request) to the file "topic.xhtml" also inside the "forum" folder the URL will be *forum.example.com/forum/topic.xhtml* instead of *forum.example.com/topic.xhtml* as I want.
2. The user is able to access *forum.example.com/anotherPageFromROOT.xhtml* normally

Could some one please help me on what I should do? Thanks!

EDIT:
I think the root cause for the first problem is the `action` generated by JSF for my `h:form`. It is always generated with `/forum/`.

Comment: proxy_pass url ends with a / (slash) what happens when you remove the slash ?

Comment: Hi @itpp13, I could not notice any difference, and both problems still exist

Comment: rewrite    /forum/([^/]+) /$1 break;

Comment: Will your app generate correct links in the returned html when accessed as `/forum.xml`?

Comment: Hi @itpp13, I believe this does the other way around. It is redirecting whatever has `/forum/` in the URL to the ROOT folder, hence my index page.
Overwriting my previous rewrite with this one, it is going to my index page at `http://example.com`.
Adding your rewrite and keeping mine, when I click in a link with `POST` request, in chrome console I got `GET http://example.com/forum/ 404 (Not Found)`.

Comment: Hi @Marki555, what do you mean by correct links? The problem is what JSF generates to the action in my `h:form`. It will always have `/forum/`, regardless the way I entered in the page

Comment: So you want `forum.example.com/` go to the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/`?

Comment: Well, I guess... considering the index is `forum.xhtml`... but I could not make it work using `http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/` in the `proxy_pass`

Comment: If you remove the last slash in proxypass it should end without a slash or adjust the rewrite to strip the slash as well (if the 404 is related to the additional slash)

Comment: Hi @itpp13 the removal of the slash in the proxy_pass caused no difference

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1 is the elephant in the room here. You cannot (afaik) tell Tomcat to serve pages from a non-ROOT folder as if they were in the ROOT folder (i.e., without prepending the folder name in generated URLs). There is a `path` attribute for `Context` setting elements, but from personal experience it's not a great idea to change that (errors in portlet deployment, portlets deployed twice with double resource usage, and so on).

If Tomcat has such a setting (tell a portlet from a folder to generate root urls) then try to use it, otherwise your only option is to set up another Tomcat with the correct files in the root folder, so the generated URLs will not have the folder prefix.

Once this problem is solved you can move on to problem #2. If you set up a different Tomcat with the forum files in the ROOT folder, the problem will have disappeared; otherwise let us know what you did.